# Angular Service Dependency Issue

Tags: angular

I have a module in a shared library as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { DialogService } from './dialog.service';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ModalModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [DialogService],
})
export class DialogModule {}
```

The `DialogService` is used throughout my application (including in lazy loaded modules) but has a dependency of `BsModalService` in the `ModalModule` (declared as a dependency in the module above).

In some places where the `DialogService` is used, the `DialogModule` has not been declared as a dependency. Therefore the `BsModalService` is missing and I get runtime errors.

How do I enforce the `DialogModule` is declared as a dependency where it is injected?

Ideally, I would get build errors with missing dependencies similar to the `strictTemplates` compilerOptions. However, I don't get any build issues, only runtime which are hard to spot in a large application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mentioning that you have used **DialogService** without importing
the **DialogModule**. My guess is that dialog service might be having the @injectable decorator saying it is provided in root

**@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})**

If so could you please try making it as follows

**@Injectable()**

It will remove dialog service from adding to app module and will enforce adding **DialogModule** to lazy loaded module instead.

Comment: I've already tried this and the build still passes even though the service is injected in places without the module import.

Comment: In that case can you check usages of DialogService and find whether it is used in another module such as app.module.ts

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not this either. I'm a bit stumped. I only get runtime errors on the page / component where it is used. Very hard to refactor.